# How to display offline data retrived from online http server

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am getting data for `ListView` from online server which is displayed fine if user is online.

But I want to display the `ListView` data in offline mode also which means it has to display the data which was retrieved when user was online.

Example : if 10 records were retrieved from online server and displayed in `ListView` when user was online.
Now, if user goes offline then `ListView` should display those 10 records retrieved previously till user goes online.

The best Example is Facebook, it shows posts in offline mode also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a database?

Comment: How do you come to know whether the user is online or offline ?

Comment: no i am not using database... i am retrieving from google app engine server

Comment: @CodeWalker i have logic to check weather the user online or offline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u should refer to these steps:

When user comes to this Activity(which has the listView in it)

1. Get all records from your database and add to your listView, show these local records(which has been loaded when user online, or no records for user first time in) to user.
2. Create an AsyncTask to call your API and get records from server, and add these records to your database
3. The listView reloadData(get records from database again), in order to show the new records to user, in AsyncTask onPostExecute function

I hope these can help u,
Best regards

Comment: THanks, should i need to create local database for this

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is save data/json in shared preferences and when you online get json from server and when offline get json from shared preference so you don't have to change other code.

```
if(online)
{
 // call http server and get json string
 // save this json string in shared preference
}
else{
//
// check if shared pre contains data ( not null) and get data from local shared pref
}
```

// further code is same as in online

Comment: which is better, weather local sqlite database or shared prefrences

Comment: depends on your use , if you only want to show data in offline mode and don't want any action related to DB then my view is use Shared preference because its uses less memory , fast and also there is less code , but if your need is related to database then Sqlite is good